# Packing a struct into a long in C

Tags: c, casting, struct

I have an `struct` containing two ints.

```
struct ref{
  int next;
  int marked;
}
```

I need to atomically compare two of these structures using CAS.

```
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&(ref1),old,new);
```

How can I cast this `struct` in order to reference it as a `long long` in c?

I tried this:

```
    __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&((long long)(ref1)),(long long)(old),(long long)(new));
```

but it gives me this error:

```
aggregate value used where an integer was expected
```

Comment: Something along the lines of  * (( long long* ) &ref1)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Casting struct into int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903820/casting-struct-into-int)

Comment: What used to be known at IBM as "the U word".

Comment: Can you say "union"? Sure, sure you can.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `ref1` is an instance of the struct type `ref`, and that `old` and `new` are already of type `long long`, you should be able to:

```
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap((long long *)&ref1, old, new);
```