# Compiler error operand of type 'div_t' where arithmetic or pointer type is required in C

Tags: c

I am trying to take the result of div function in c, cast it to an int and then add that int to a greater int value. I get the error of the title all the time, and i can not understand why

```
out = div(n, 10);
r = (int) out;
a = a + r;
```

Compiler shows me as an error the second line and out specifically.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Let's say we had `n == 5`. What do you expect `r` to be equal to?

Comment: r is out, typecasted as int number, because out is a div_t type of variable. so if i add a with out i'll get an error. that's what i am trying to do basically

Comment: n is a random integer value always

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903820/casting-struct-into-int

Comment: @BillLynch first instance of `div_t` casting error that I can find.

Comment: Bill Lynch's question basically was what you expect to be the result of such a cast. What value do you expect to be in `r` afterwards? Should it be one of the 2 members of the struct (in that case: which one?), the sum, the average, whatever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `div_t`, as returned by `div()`, is a structure containing two numbers, the quotient and the remainder.

```
typedef struct {
  int quot;
  int rem;
} div_t;
```

If you've used the `div()` function then you want either `r = out.rem` or `r = out.quot`, not clear which from your example.

If all you want is the quotient, though, `r = n / 10` is simpler.  And if all you want is the remainder, `r = n % 10` (for non-negative n).  `div()` is useful in the case where you need both values - the actual divide instruction on many machines can deliver both results from one instruction.

Comment: Note that the standard does not specify the order of `quot` and `rem` in the structure — it just specifies that they must both be present.  [§7.22.6.2 The `div`, `ldiv` and `lldiv` functions ¶3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.6.2p3): _The `div`, `ldiv`, and `lldiv` functions return a structure of type `div_t`, `ldiv_t`, and `lldiv_t`, respectively, comprising both the quotient and the remainder. The structures shall contain (in either order) the members `quot` (the quotient) and `rem` (the remainder), each of which has the same type as the arguments `numer` and `denom`._

Answer (score 1):

`div(x, y)` function does **both** `x / y` **and** `x % y` in one operation. It returns a structure with `rem` member having the result of `x % y` and `quot` having the result of `x / y`. In your case you would access these values as `out.quot` and `out.rem` and both members are already values of type `int`. Casting a structure containing *two integers* into an integer does not make any sense.

---

On many processors there is a single division opcode that always calculates both, so if you need both, then `div(x, y)` is giving the other one for free. One common instance is converting a number into a decimal string which requires repeatedly taking quotient and remainder with 10; here you can use `div` efficiently for positive numbers:

```
res = div(n, 10);
next_digit = res.rem;
// place next_digit into the string
n = res.quot;
```